# Missing conda.exe

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried installing Anaconda Distribution but it's not launching. I tried launching Anaconda Navigator, it's not starting up. I tried using CLI conda, it's not working as well.

Fixes I have tried but didn't work.
 - Reinstalled twice 
 - Added directory to system path

None of these work so I tried looking at the scripts folder, and I found no conda.exe. Note that I have reinstalled this twice. Now I'm wondering why conda exe is not installing to my system.

How should this be fixed?

Update #1: Restarting the system would fix this error.
Update #2: This will reload the CMD.

Comment: You have no other folder on your system except scripts? Not a single one? There's absolutely no other place to look for conda.exe except that one and only folder? There is positively no other place on your entire computer where conda.exe could be located except that lonely scripts folder?

Comment: There are other folders but the conda.exe should be inside the scripts folder according to some how to's in installing Anaconda.

Comment: And you've searched the rest of your system to make sure it's not in another location, of course, before posting here saying that you don't have conda.exe on your machine? In case *some how tos* are not correct or outdated, or you're simply in the wrong scripts folder? *I can't find my car keys. I looked in my car, and they're not there. I don't know what to do!* It would be much more useful to say *I've searched my entire computer, and there is no conda.exe to be found*. You've also provided no useful details other than *it doesn't work, and I looked in one folder. What should I do?*

Comment: Yup. I got it fixed though, newbie mistake. I skipped the step of restarting the system after uninstalling before reinstalling it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only had to restart the system after uninstalling before reinstalling it again.